# How to set bulma navbar dropdown open on the left not on the right?

Tags: html, css, bulma

When I open bulma dropdown it gets opened on the right and some part is even outside from screen. How can I force it to pen dropdown on the left?

Currently, it looks like this:
[image]

So the goal is to open it on the left from the Account item

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="dropdown navigation">
  <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-active">
    <a class="navbar-link">
      Docs
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Overview
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Elements
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Components
      </a>
      <hr class="navbar-divider">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        Version 0.9.1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can be it solved?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documention about the dropdown component,](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/#right-aligned) you can add the `is-right` class to have a right-aligned dropdown, so the overflow will be on the left side.
It also works on navbar's dropdowns, your code should look like this :

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="dropdown navigation">
  <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-active">
    <a class="navbar-link">
      Docs
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-dropdown is-right">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Overview
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Elements
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Components
      </a>
      <hr class="navbar-divider">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        Version 0.9.1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Result :
[image]